# Angular Username field validation

Tags: php, html, html5-canvas

I am doing the password field validation so that user can't enter the password value of substring of username.

```
<input id="password" name="password" type="password" required data-ng-model="user.password" data-ng-minlength="8" data-ng-maxlength="32" data-no-substring ***data-no-substring-value="user.username"*** data-ui-validate="{ validatePassword : 'validatePassword($value)'}" data-nlc-validation-handler data-check-strength="signup.password" />
     <span class="inline-error" data-ng-show="signup.password.$dirty && signup.password.$invalid"><i class="left-arrow"></i></span>
     <span id="password-strength">{{signup.password.strengthText}}</span>
</div>
```

Here the cases

- Case-1 when user enter username field value first and then password field value, it is working fine as validation setup in password field.
- Case-2 NOT WORKING
  When they first enter the password field value and then username field value, it is not working.

Please suggest the way to fix this issue.

Comment: Where are you doing the validation, in the controller or in the view?

Comment: Can you show us some code pls ?

Comment: I am doing validation in HTML page only.

Comment: For the password field ,using the,
data-no-substring-value="user.username"

<input id="password" name="password" type="password" required data-ng-model="user.password" data-ng-minlength="8" data-ng-maxlength="32" data-no-substring data-no-substring-value="user.username" data-ui-validate="{ validatePassword : 'validatePassword($value)'}" data-nlc-validation-handler data-check-strength="signup.password" />

Comment: Any one can help please?